tool or shortcut for copying part of the terminal
I apologize for the vagueness of this question but I saw this tool over 4 years ago at this point.
I remember working with a colleague at one point who knew a bash tool or shortcut that allowed him to somehow flip the mode of the command-line interface such that instead of entering a command into the prompt, he was able to essentially freeze the screen and use the navigation arrows to specify what text output on the command-line to copy to the clipboard and I am trying to figure out what that tool was?

He was probably use tmux or screen

This question is similar to: Terminal - copy from CLI without using mouse. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

answering my own question but tmux has nice way of copy/pasting part of the terminal

I converted your answer to a comment since as it was just a link to some video, it isn't actually giving a solution.
